# how to copy python modules into python lib directory

Tags: python, linux, module, copy

I have some python modules to copy into my Linux computer.
I found out that I need to copy them into one of the directory that python searches or else show a new path for it.
1. when I tried to copy files into /usr/bin/..../python2.6 .. its not allowing me.
   how do I make it.
2. Also do tell me how do I add a new search path ?

> please guide me in detail. I have very less knowledge in linux
>
> Also please tell me how do I get over this kind of problems myself. Is there any small book or a kind of to learn?

Comment: You almost certainly want to use the modules' setup.py scripts to install them, rather than manually placing them in your pythonpath.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a proper Python package on top of setuptools and register your command-line frontends using the 'console_scripts' entry-point.